# How to go trough a list without for loops

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to go trough a list called `message`, that is a simple word and encode it.

I also have a dictionary called `symbol_code_table`, that has the code for each letter in the word.

Something like this:

```
symbol_code_table = {'a': '011', 'b': '10', 'c': '010', 'd': '00', 'n': '11'}
message = "caba"
```

So the result will be something like this:

```
010 011 10 011
```

Below, I show the function that does this

```
def encode_huff (message , symbol_code_table):

    binary_code = ''

    for i in message:
      if (i in symbol_code_table):
        binary_code += symbol_code_table[i]
```

I wanted to know if there's another way to go trough the message without having to use a `for loop`

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I don't see how you could do that without using a loop

Comment: Your code does not produce your reported output, even if you were to `return` / `print()` the `binary_code`. The space is missing.

Comment: The only way to do this without a loop is to a) write every operation performed in your loop line by line, or b) [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) your code.

Comment: @RoadRunner It is unclear if the question is "How do I accomplish this without the `for <item> in <iterable>:` syntax?" or "How do I accomplish this without repeating over the list?" My answer below addresses the first one while you are reading it as the second.

Comment: If you don't care about spaces, you could write: `message.translate(str.maketrans(symbol_code_table))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can with the functional paradigm, here is using `map`:

```
binary_code = "".join(map(lambda s: symbol_table.get(s, ""), message))
```

Comment: Please fix your code with `"` or `'`, instead of `“`. Otherwise this is probably what the accepted answer should be,

Comment: You probably should note that this still loops over `message`. It is just hidden in the `map()` function.

Comment: @norok2 indeed, I noticed that too but can’t find an easy way to do so from an iPhone :/

Comment: @code-apprentice: I think it’s obvious that some sort of iteration is required. The question, though, specifically asks about “for loops”, not “any loop of any kind” :)

Comment: @smassey You and I both think that iteration here is obvious, but future visitors may not. The question is ambiguous about that distinction. The title says "without loops" while the body says "without having to use a for loop". I think it is important to clarify that while `map()` isn't an explicit `for` loop, it is still a loop.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

`binary_code = ' '.join(list(map(lambda s: symbol_code_table.get(s),message)))`

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know if there's another way to go trough the message without without having to use a for loop.

You can use a list comprehension instead:

```
binary_code = ''.join([symbol_code_table[i] for i in message])
```

Note that this is still a loop. In other words, it isn't any more efficient to run. The syntax is just much more concise.

Comment: i think this answer does not answer the actual question

Comment: @AdamBajger Why not?

Comment: because the question was, if there is a way to avoid for loop. You suggested a for loop as a solution.

Comment: @AdamBajger I'm sorry... where is the for loop in my answer? There is a list comprehension, which is a looping structure, but it is not a for loop. Also, the caveat at the end of my answer, clarifies this distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would say no. You need to visit each element at least once in order to encode it, which always leads to some form of a for loop, however nicely you write it.

If you need it only to avoid the "for" keyword in the python code, use tail-recursion.

If you are looking for a speedup, you can split the message into chunks, encode them in parallel threads, then join results in correct order to get the full encoded message.